# asp.net/vb webpage not redirecting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've got some legacy websites that have been migrated to Windows Server 2019 and have found out that the code no longer seems to be functioning correctly.  This is code for a simple poll/voting system.  The problem that I'm currently running into is that when any of the links are clicked, it technically doesn't redirect from the page it's on.  for example the `PollList.aspx` page (www.mysite/admin/PollList.aspx) has a few links on it.  one of them is to load up the page `PollEdit.aspx` so a new poll can be added.  the URL it's supposed to redirect to is `www.mysite/admin/PollEdit.aspx?ID=0` (new poll only created by admins).  however what it redirects to is: `www.mysite/admin/PollList.aspx/PollEdit.aspx?ID=0`  and stays on the current page.

Can someone show me what's broken?  This was migrated from a Windows Server 2008r2 to Windows Server 2019.  Let me know if there's any info needed.

below is the related content from the PollList.aspx page.  everything else seems to be working just fine:

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <a href="UserEdit.aspx?id=0">Edit Voter Permissions</a>         
    <h1><center>Polls</center></h1>

    <asp:repeater id="lstPolls" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <%= "<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=4 align=center width=80% >" %>
            <%= "<tr><td></td><td align=center><font size=2><a href=PollEdit.aspx?ID=0>[new poll]</a></font></td></tr>" %>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%="<tr bgcolor=#B3C9EF>"%>
            <%# PrintPollItem(Container.DataItem)%>
            <%= "</tr>" %>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <%= "<tr bgcolor=""#DFEBFF"">" %>
            <%# PrintPollItem(Container.DataItem)%>
            <%= "</tr>" %>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate><%= "</table>" %></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:repeater>

</form>
```

and below is the code behind content for the PrintPollItem() func:

```
Protected Function PrintPollItem(ByVal myPoll As BLL.Poll) As String
    Dim txtTemp As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    txtTemp.Append("<td>")
    txtTemp.Append("<a href=PollEdit.aspx?ID=" & myPoll.ID.ToString() & ">")
    txtTemp.Append(myPoll.Name)
    txtTemp.Append("</a>")
    txtTemp.Append("</td>")
    txtTemp.Append("<td width=200 align=center>")

    Select Case myPoll.OpenStatus
        Case -1
            txtTemp.Append("poll closed: <a href=PollResults.aspx?ID=" & myPoll.ID.ToString() & "><font size=2>[view results]</font></a>")
        Case 1
                txtTemp.Append("poll open: <a href=PollList.aspx?ID=" & myPoll.ID.ToString() & "&Action=close><font size=2>[end now]</font></a><br /><a href=PollResults.aspx?ID=" & myPoll.ID.ToString() & "><font size=2>[view results]</font></a>")
        Case Else
            txtTemp.Append("poll pending: <a href=PollList.aspx?ID=" & myPoll.ID.ToString() & "&Action=open><font size=2>[open now]</font></a>")
    End Select

    txtTemp.Append("</td>")

    Return txtTemp.ToString()

End Function
```

Comment: You may also need quotes around the href values, either single or escaped double quotes

Comment: Incidentally, you could use the [StringBuilder.AppendFormat] method: `txtTemp.AppendFormat("<a href=""/admin/PollEdit.aspx?ID={0}"">", myPoll.ID)`. The two consecutive `""` make a single `"` in the resulting string.

Comment: Oops, missed out the link: [StringBuilder.AppendFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

href you can give full path or relative path
you can use / or ../ or ~/ Before Assigning Link, That indicates current Files or Folder

Try href=/PollEdit.aspx

Comment: Probably `/admin/PollEdit.aspx`, from the question ;)